# What is the inverse function?

Tags: integration

$\lambda:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ smooth, $\lambda>0$.

Let
$$
F(s(t))=t_0+\int_{x_0}^{s(t)}\frac{1}{\lambda(x(w))}\, dw=t.
$$

Hence
$$
s(t)=F^{-1}(t),
$$
isn't it?

But what is $F^{-1}(t)$?

I do not see.

See [Understand a proof concerning a theorem about topologically equivalent systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503707/understand-a-proof-concerning-a-theorem-about-topologically-equivalent-systems) for the background. Sorry forgot to give the link earlier.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a constant or a function? It seems like $s(t_{0}) = x_0$, by that equation. Do you have any more information to give us? I find it a bit strange that $x$ is a function that takes in an input $x_0$.

Comment: @Santeri Added it. Maybe instead of $x_0$ as integral limit there is $0$. Cannot read it clearly, thought it might be $x_0$.

Comment: I think it should be $s_0$.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: In your other question, it shows that the integral was arrived at through a separable differential equation. The time is integrated from $t_0$ to $t$, so the dependent variable $s$ should be integrated from $s(t_{0}) = s_0$ to $s(t)$.

Comment: Ok. The main reason I asked this question here because I am not sure if the transformed times s(t) are in the existence intervall of the solution x(t). If not, the expression x(s(t)) would make no sense I think.

Comment: But when separating, we usually have one integral from $x_0$ to x and the other from $t_0$ to t. So I thouht this integral here should go from $x_0$ cause the other integral already is from $t_0$ to t.